# Calling a function from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I've got a pile of data in one worksheet that I am trying to save to individual workbooks based on values in several columns. The approach I am taking (for better or worse!) is to copy the relevant worksheet (and macros) to a new workbook, save it with an appropriate name (let's say "temp.xlsx"), and then to cleanse the data in that new workbook by deleting irrelevant rows (function called deleteInfo). This all has to be done without altering the original workbook, as per company policy.

I can copy the stuff over no problem, but I'm having serious issues calling macros in the new workbook then.

I have tried:

```
Application.Run "'temp.xlsx'!deleteInfo"

ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run deleteInfo

Application.Run ("'C:\user\.....\temp.xlsx'!deleteInfo")
```

But none have worked.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overcomplicated the problem by attempting to run your cleanup after the data has exited the file with your VBA code.

You could duplicate the sheet *inside the source file*, run corrections on the duplicate, and then move the duplicate out into your new workbook once it's been cleaned.

Comment: Agreed, it is overcomplicated. I'd love to clean it up in the original workbook. Sadly, company policy dictates that the source file can't be changed.

Comment: Two possible workarounds on that: 1) you could duplicate the whole workbook and use that as a working copy, or else 2) just don't save the file between duplicating the tab and moving it out of the file. If the source file is in an identical state before and after your macro runs and none of the original tabs were ever edited, I wouldn't quantify that as a change, and I doubt the policy would make that distinction either.

Comment: 1) leaves me with the same problem, unable to call macros in a duplicate. I could manually start a new function, but there may be 10s of files to do it on. 2) sadly falls foul of said policy. Thanks for the suggestions though.